# How to sort items in mysql based on data from another table?

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have the following tables:

word_list:

```
id | word
1  | ball
2  | car 
3  | small
```

items_word_match:

```
itemid | wordid | in_title | in_description
1      | 1      | 1        | 0 //The word #1 occurs once in the title of the item 
1      | 3      | 0        | 2 //The word #3 occurs twice in the title of the item
3      | 3      | 1        | 2
2      | 1      | 1        | 0
```

search:

```
wordid | importance 
1      | 1
2      | 5 
3      | 2 //word #3 is more important than the word #1 but less so than word #2
```

I want to sort the items based on the keywords from the search table and how important the keywords are.
And if the keyword is in the title the importance should increase by 1 and if the word appears 2 times the importance of the word should be importance*2

Comment: don't apologize for *bad* English. It's not a problem as long as we know what you **mean**. And besides your English is **not** bad at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of those answers from Denis or Johan are correct. Instead you could use this:

```
select 
    itemid, 
    sum(word_importance) as item_importance
from
    (select 
        itemid, 
        search.wordid,
        (
            in_title * (importance + 1)
            + in_description * importance
        ) as word_importance
    from 
        items_word_match, 
        search 
    where 
        i.wordid = s.wordid 
    )
group by itemid
```

As Johan pointed out, you need to add an order clause to the end, `, order by item_importance desc`

Comment: your query doesn't SORT by importance, add an `order by` clause because the implicit ordering in the `group by` is the wrong one. BTW I wasn't trying to answer the question in the body, but answering the question in the title in general. Nice looking query though.

Answer (score 1):

Feel a bit lazy today, so I'm just going to answer the question in the title:

> How to sort items in mysql based on data from another table ?

You can sort the outcome of a query by any criterium you wish.

```
SELECT word_list.* FROM word_list
INNER JOIN search ON (search.wordid = wordlist.id)
ORDER BY search.importance, word_list.id DESC
```

Note that the `JOIN` needed to link the two tables together can have a profound effect on which rows in the `word_list` table are selected, but you need to do a `JOIN` somehow.
Otherwise MySQL will not know what the relationship between the two tables is and cannot sort the fields.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    i.itemid
  , SUM( i.in_description * s.importance 
       + i.in_title * ( s.importance + 1 )
       )
    AS item_importance
FROM
    items_word_match i
        LEFT JOIN
    search s
          ON s.wordid = i.wordid
GROUP BY
    i.itemid
ORDER BY
    item_importance DESC
```

---

CORRECTION:

I used `LEFT JOIN` catch the case when some words do not appear in the `search` table. But then the importance of those words seems appropriate to be `0` and not `NULL`, so the SUM should be changed into:

```
  , SUM( i.in_description * COALESCE(s.importance, 0) 
       + i.in_title * COALESCE(s.importance, 1) 
       )
```

Comment: +1 best answer, note that you can shorten the query by saying `ORDER BY item_importance` instead of `ORDER BY SUM(....`

Comment: @Johan: Yes, thnx. I keep forgetting that because you can't use an alias in another calculated field. But you can in `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 0):

your order by clause can contain fields from any of the tables:

```
select table1.*
from table1
join table2 using (table1_id)
order by table2.field, table1.field, etc.
```